# str.format on non-template string silently ignores template arguments

Tags: python, string

```
>>> 'potato'.format(123)
'potato'
>>> 'potato'.format(kw='hello')
'potato'
```

I really expected an exception to be raised here rather than templating silently ignored.

Why is this allowed in python, what are valid use cases where this behaviour is preferable?

Comment: Extra arguments are ignored for template strings *with* placeholders too.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that and thought it was strange for the same reason (especially since partial templating `'hello {x} {y}'.format(x=123)` raises exception rather than returning `'hello 123 {y}'`

Comment: *Missing* parameters is very hard to recover from. What if there is more than whitespace around `{x}`? What do you include or omit? What if there is a field width included for the missing parameter, do you include that width still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring extra arguments makes the format *far more flexible*. Note that this isn't about 'non-template' strings; if you do have placeholders, extra arguments are *still ignored*:

```
>>> 'potato {}'.format(123, 456)
'potato 123'
>>> 'potato {spam}'.format(spam=123, eggs=456)
'potato 123'
```

By ignoring extra arguments you can use a variable template, pick one, and pass in all *possible* interpolation values, or pass in `vars(self)` to make for a flexible format based on the current instance:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '<Foo object, spam={spam!r}, eggs={eggs!r}'.format(**vars(self))
```

without having to worry about extra parameters you are not going to use for this specific template.

Comment: @wim: use the `repr()` of value instead of the value itself. Similarly, there is a `!s` as well to use `str(value)`.